# How to update row sets with a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am fairly new to SQL and I am trying to write an update statement that will in essence duplicate data from one column to another for 600 records.

ex. **ADDRESS.FIRST_NAME** i.e."JOHN" would be copied in **ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5** "JOHN" for all 600 records. I have four columns this needs to happen in. and this is as far as I have gotten.

> **DECLARE** @fName CHAR, @lName CHAR, @email CHAR, @phoneNum CHAR  
> **SET** @fName = (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM ADDRESS INNER JOIN CUST
>   ON ADDRESS.CUST_CODE =    CUST.CUST_CODE WHERE CUST.CATEGORY_CODE =
>   'SR' AND ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5 IS NULL)  
> **SET**@lName = (SELECT
>   LAST_NAME FROM ADDRESS INNER JOIN CUST ON ADDRESS.CUST_CODE =
>   CUST.CUST_CODE WHERE CUST.CATEGORY_CODE = 'SR' AND ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5
>   IS NULL) 
> **SET** @email = (SELECT EMAIL FROM ADDRESS INNER
>   JOIN CUST ON ADDRESS.CUST_CODE = CUST.CUST_CODE WHERE
>   CUST.CATEGORY_CODE = 'SR' AND ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5 IS NULL)
>   
> **SET** @phoneNum = (SELECT TEL1 FROM ADDRESS INNER JOIN CUST ON
>   ADDRESS.CUST_CODE = CUST.CUST_CODE WHERE CUST.CATEGORY_CODE = 'SR' AND
>   ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5 IS NULL) 
> **UPDATE** dbo.ADDRESS 
>   
> **SET** ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5 = @fName+@lName, ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR6 =
>   @email,  ADDRESS.CUSTMEMO1 = @phoneNum 
> **FROM** ADDRESS
>   
> **INNER JOIN** CUST 
> **ON** ADDRESS.CUST_CODE = CUST.CUST_CODE
>   
> **WHERE** CUST.CATEGORY_CODE = 'SR'  
> **AND** ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5
>   IS NULL  
> **AND** ADDRESS.EMAIL = @email

When I run this statement I get the error below

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Comment: Mysql and sql server are 2 different things.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this for SQL Server.

```
UPDATE dbo.ADDRESS
SET 
    ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5 = FIRST_NAME + LAST_NAME,
    ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR6 = EMAIL,
    ADDRESS.CUSTMEMO1 = TEL1 
FROM CUST 
WHERE ADDRESS.CUST_CODE = CUST.CUST_CODE
    AND CUST.CATEGORY_CODE = 'SR'
    AND ADDRESS.CUSTCHAR5 IS NULL
    AND ADDRESS.EMAIL = @email
```